# Connect Remotely to Centos installed on Vmware

Tags: ssh, vmware, remote-access, centos7

I have CentOS7 installed on Vmware, and I'm able to access it through SSH from my computer where Vmware is installed. I need to access my virtual machine from another computer. Is this possible? and what are the steps to complete this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You need to bridge your network adapter with the one on the VM, and then it will be accessible the same way your PC is.

Comment: when I change the network on the virtual machine to bridged, I lose connectivity.

Comment: What is the network config for the VM? If i am not mistaken, you should have NAT enabled somewhere.

Comment: Yes it is enabled. Network Adapter Settings: Nat, If I change it to Bridged I lose connection in the virtual machine.